# How to create stratified folds for repeatedcv in caret?

Tags: machine-learning, r-caret, cross-validation

The way to create stratified folds for cv in caret is like this

```
library(caret)
library(data.table)
train_dat <- data.table(group = c(rep("group1",10), rep("group2",5)), x1 = rnorm(15), x2 = rnorm(15), label = factor(c(rep("treatment",15), rep("control",15))))

folds <- createFolds(train_dat[, group], k = 5)

fitCtrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", index = folds, classProbs = T, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
train(label~., data = train_dat[, !c("group"), with = F], trControl = fitCtrl, method = "xgbTree", metric = "ROC")
```

To balance group1 and group2, the creation of fold indexes is based on "group" variable.

However, is there any way to createFolds for repeatedcv in caret? So, I can have a balanced split for repeatedcv. Should I combined several createFolds and run trainControl?

```
trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", index = many_repeated_folds)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! @gung

Comment: I have added a reproducible example. What do you think? @gung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createMultiFolds` is probably what you are interested in.

Comment: hi, i don't understand how this function handles the "stratified"